# Operating on Nested Tuples using Map function

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested, tuples

```
rect = [(2,4),(3,5),(4,3),(5,5),(6,2),(3,9)] 

areas=[] 

def area(r):                         
     for i in rect:
        a = i[0]
        b = i[1]
        c = a*b
        areas.append(c)                
     return c

area(rect)                             
print(areas)
```

The above function runs fine.

It prints - `[8, 15, 12, 25, 12, 27]`

BUT when I use Map:

```
print(list(map(area, rect))
```

it prints - `[27, 27, 27, 27, 27]`

How can I get the above result correct with the Map function?

Comment: It doesn't work because your function `area(r)` is returning last computed area.

Comment: This also has to do with the fact that you don't actually use the function's argument `r` and always operating on `rect`, so it doesn't really matter what you pass to the function. You could call it `area("hello world")` and it will still work...

Comment: AND, by the way, if you will do `print(aread(rect))` you will notice that this simply prints `27`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map calls `area` on every element in the `rect` list, therefore

```
map(area, rect)
```

would result in:

```
[area(rect[0]),area(rect[1]),area(rect[2]),... ] = [27,27,...]
```

in python it is preferred to use list comprehension:

```
out = [a*b for a,b in rect]
```